# Why my code only get tweets in latest 1 or 2 minutes in Twitter4j

Tags: java, api, twitter, mapreduce, tweets

Said that Twitter API will give tweets in 7 days, but when i tried to implement my code using java, i just get the result of tweets less than enough. It just covered tweets in 1 until 2 minutes. The number of data or tweets is far from my need. Is that any error on my code?
here my code:

```
public class TweetPublic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("key")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("key")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("key")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("key");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        FileOutputStream fos;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        try {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Charlie Siagian/Desktop/data.doc");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

            try {

                Query query = new Query("(#hadoop) OR (#bigdata) OR (#data) OR (#datamining) "
                        + "OR (#mapreduce) OR (#flume) OR (#semanticanalytic) OR (#dataset) OR (#rdbms)"
                        + "OR (#database) OR (#mysql)");
                QueryResult result;
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText() + "\n=======\n"
                            + tweet.getCreatedAt());
                    dos.writeBytes("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText() + "\n"
                            + tweet.getCreatedAt() + "\n=======\n");
                }

                System.exit(0);
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try other keywords which are more popular?

Comment: i have tried it, but in this case , i just need to search tweet related to those query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a popular query, so you are only getting the last 10 tweets.  You can walk back in chunks of 100.  Use "&max_id=*ID*&count=100"

So add an outer loop and remember the minimum id you have seen on previous iterations. For the first iteration, don't set max_id, and then keep updating max_id to the new *minimum* on subsequent iterations.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23hadoop+OR+%23bigdata+OR+%23data+OR+%23datamining+OR+%23mapreduce+OR+%23flume+OR+%23semanticanalytic+OR+%23dataset+OR+%23rdbms+OR+%23database+OR+%23mysql&max_id=758939297495982100&count=100
```

Looks like that is available here http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setMaxId-long-

More general docs https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: how can i add that code to my own code above? help me please, i am confuse with max_id,